# Android Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm using Navigation Drawer Activity in my app and I have a little problem.
When I select item on navigation items the menu icon change to arrow like the image below: 
[image]

And what I want is this :

[image]

Second thing , When navigate from main fragment to child fragment , how can I enable back function when I click arrow icon?

This is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    displayView();

 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    Fragment fragment = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();
    String title ="";
    boolean isOK = true;
    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
         fragment = new HomeFragment();
        title = getString(R.string.nav_item_home);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_store) {
        if (MyHelper.licationServiceIsActive(MainActivity.this)){
        fragment = new MagasinsFragment();
        title = getString(R.string.nav_item_store);}else {
            isOK = false;
        }

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_catalog) {
        fragment = new AllCatalogueFragment();
        title = getString(R.string.nav_item_catalog);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_parking) {
        if (MyHelper.licationServiceIsActive(MainActivity.this)){
        fragment = new ParkingFragment();
        title = getString(R.string.nav_item_parking);}else {
            isOK = false;
        }

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {
        fragment = new AllListFragment();
        title = getString(R.string.nav_item_cart);
        //fragment = new ListeFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
        title = getString(R.string.action_settings);
    }
    if (isOK) {
if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);


    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    // set the toolbar title
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
  }else {
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setTitle("Information");
dialog.setMessage("Le service de localisation est désactivé.\nVoulez-vous l'activer?");
dialog.setPositiveButton("Activer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        //get gps
    }
});
dialog.setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
dialog.show();
   }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: please show your toolbar related code

Comment: Please paste your code with your question...

Comment: I edited my question by adding my code on mainActivity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should disable the up icon of the `ActionBar` or `Toolbar`

For `ActionBar`:

`getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:
You might be using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` method due to which it changes the menu button to back button!! Simply remove that code if you are using it.

For Second Question:

To implement Back functionality in Fragments you just need to `PopBackStack()`

for example:

```
   public void moveBack()
    {
//FM =FragmentManager object
        if(FM!=null && FM.getBackStackEntryCount()>0)
       {
         FM.popBackStack() //to pop fragment from backstack
       }
       else
       {
         finish();  //for activity exit
       }
    }
```

make sure you add fragment to BackStack.

Comment: For the first one , When I removed ActionBarDrawerToggle method, even menu icon is not showing. But I want  it to work, to change menu icon to arrow icon only when I navigate to fragment wich different from main fragments. For the second one , I want when the menu icon changes to arrow , when I click it I come back to previous fragment.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate through BAck Button try this, On the Onclick of back button call `OnBackPressed();` method to get back to previous activity.

Comment: I want ,when the menu icon changes to arrow , when I click it I come back to previous fragment  not when on back button pressed.

Comment: OnBackPressed(); is the method, you can call any where. Calling this method will do the same event which occurs on back button pressed. This method is not limited to back button only. @Rockers23

Comment: I know this but how can I call it when I click on Arrow icon?

Comment: Follow this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments and also have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190047/using-onbackpressed-in-android-fragments

Comment: I already did this when back button is pressed. But what I want is when I clicked on arrow icon on the action bar.

Comment: onBackPressed if for Acitivity and the question is for fragment @PriyaJagtap

Comment: Are you using a toolbar? @Rockers23

Comment: This answer is for fragment. Have a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558568/manage-toolbars-navigation-and-back-button-from-fragment-in-android @Rockers23

Comment: Yes @SatishSilveri

Comment: You might be using a imageview to show menu icon in toolbar right? @Rockers23

Comment: I don't use an imageview.