# How can I open a fragment from my Adapter onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to open a new Fragment called `optionsFragment` from my RecyclerView Adapter onlick. I tried a lot of tutorials but I'm too stupid for this.

The new fragment should be has a back arrow button at the left top corner to go back to the RecyclerView.

Please help me.

This is my onClick function for my holder in the adapter:

```js
FragmentManager benutzerlisteManager = ((NavigationDrawerActivity)customContext).getSupportFragmentManager();

               BenutzerOverviewFragment benutzerOverviewFragment = new BenutzerOverviewFragment();

               benutzerlisteManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_navigation_drawer,
                       benutzerOverviewFragment,
                       benutzerOverviewFragment.getTag())
                       .addToBackStack(null)
                       .commit();
```

I've tried the code at the top but the app is crashing with this error:

> NavigationDrawerActivity@b42040b must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: open activity and in activity u can open fragment u can't open fragment whithout any activity

Comment: Pass `FragmentManager` to adapter constructor and use later or you can simply call method from activity or register interface and implement it to your activity class

Comment: @DarshanKachhadiya I have a navigation drawer activity where I open the RecyclerView as a fragment. And now I need to open the new fragment when I click a row in my RecyclerView

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you load new fragment from adapter:

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 OptionsFragment optionsFrag = new OptionsFragment ();
((ActivityName)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, optionsFrag,"OptionsFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
        });
```

and for back press icon follow this :
[Manage toolbar's navigation and back button from fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558568/manage-toolbars-navigation-and-back-button-from-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an Interface:
   `public interface MyItemClickListener {
   void onItemClick(int position); }`
2. Implement this interface to your Activity/Fragment:

`class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyItemClickListener{ }`

3. pass the object of your Interface to Adapter:

`MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this); //this is instance of MyItemClickListner`

4. Call method of interface from the adapter:

`// OnClickListener for holder`

`holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
`@Override`
`public void onClick(final View v) {`
`mMyClickListner.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());`
`}`
`});`

This will call onItemClick in you activity/fragment. From this method declaration, you can open fragment:

`mMyClickListner.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());`

Answer (score 1):

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();

Fragment fragment = new DetailFragment();

activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

You can write in onClick

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have **activity** object.
You can use **activity** object like this

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

            activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new YourFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();


            }
        });
```

Comment: `context.getFragmentManager()` this will not return your `FragmentManager`. Context should be your activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it**

```
private Context mContext;
ArrayList<Inquiry> mInquiryYearsLists;
InquiryFragment mInquiryFragment;

public InquiryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Inquiry> arrayListingg) {
    this.mInquiryYearsLists = arrayListingg;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

            mInquiryFragment = new InquiryDashboardFragment();

            FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mInquiryFragment). mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    });


}
```