# Xamarin resource ID of Toolbar back/home button does not match Resource.Id.home

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a Toolbar for an activity in Android in Xamarin. I have enabled the back/home button with `SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`. I am trying to capture the event of pressing the back/home button with the following code, as instructed by [this and many other stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558568/manage-toolbars-navigation-and-back-button-from-fragment-in-android):

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnOptionsItemSelected() called: " + item.ItemId);
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.home:
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Home button pressed");
                    Finish();
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
```

When I press the back button, `OnOptionsItemSelected` is called, but `item.ItemId` is **not** equal to `Resource.Id.home`. The former is 16908332 (tested on two different devices) but the latter is 2131492903. How can I capture the home/back button from the toolbar in Xamarin? One possible option is to hardcode the back button ID as 16908332, but I do not know if that number will stay the same permanently.

Comment: You want the system resource ID, not one from your app. In Xamarin, I believe it's [`Android.Resource.Id.Home`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Id.Home/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong resource, you want the one from the Android space:

```
Android.Resource.Id.Home
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the Resource.Id.Home for? To confuse people and have them spend hours searching until they find this?  :))

Comment: @asnyder Using Resource.Id.home (technically `R.Id.home`) in theory you can build your own navigation stack and thus define your own "home", personally I have never seen it done and not really sure how it would apply to an app  (maybe defining a launcher that uses a stacked navigation for drilling down and back, .... ?)

Answer (score 0):

The right one to use is

```
case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                Finish();
                break;
```